# How do I use (a config file for) external header files that contain compile time dependend #defines?

Tags: c++, cmake

Imagine I am compiling (a static) library `libfoo.a` that provides a header file `foo.h`. I will link my application `APP` against `libfoo.a` and `#include <foo.h>` in my source code. `libfoo` is using `CMake` as a build system with user defined variables, such as `BUILD_WITH_OPTION_BAR` that are passed on as definitions to the compiler:

`ADD_DEFINITIONS(BUILD_WITH_OPTION_BAR)`

Inside `foo.h` we will find `#ifdef` declarations using this option:

```
#ifdef BUILD_WITH_OPTION_BAR
   typedef long long int fooInt;
#else
   typedef int fooInt;
#endif
```

**My question is:** How am I supposed to know inside my `APP` that `libfoo.a` was build with or without `BUILD_WITH_OPTION_BAR`?

*In other words:* Where and when do I have to define `BUILD_WITH_OPTION_BAR` inside my `APP`?

My basic understanding is that the library `libfoo` should provide some kind of `config.h` file that is included inside `foo.h`, but how do you get an **optional** `#define BUILD_WITH_OPTION_BAR` in there at compile time (of `libfoo`)?

*I found this related question: [add_definitions vs. configure_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781222/add-definitions-vs-configure-file) but it doesn't discuss **how** this is actually accomplished.*

Comment: Do you really need to know what the library was built with? Why not just make use of the `fooInt` typedef? If it really matters which one is used, then perhaps it shouldn't be in the library?

Comment: Yes, I really need to know, because if I use `fooInt` then which `typedef` will I get? It has to be the same as in the linked library, right? And that only works if I know what `libfoo` was build with and `BUILD_WITH_OPTION_BAR` is defined (or undefined).

Comment: @ruslo thanks for pointing out a good answer - I might suggest editing that question / headline to make it easier to find for others in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do it is to create a "config.h" file with the defines instead of passing them as command-line arguments to the compiler. You can the distribute the config.h file with the library file.

Cmake provides a mechanism for generating such a file.

```
CONFIGURE_FILE(<src filename>, <dest filename>)
```

Typically the source file is named "config.h.in" and the output file is named "config.h". In the .in file lines like this:

```
#cmakedefine BUILD_WITH_OPTION_BAR 1
```

are replaced with

```
#define BUILD_WITH_OPTION_BAR 1
```

if the option is enabled, otherwise they're commented out.

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/configure_file.html and http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Write_Platform_Checks for more.